# How to show message on table when data is not available

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have created inline editable table. When data is not available, it should the "No record display. But I am not able to show it. I tried this:

```html
<ng-template #viewable>
  <ng-container *ngIf="data && data.length > 0; else noDataToShow">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let head of headers">
      <ng-container *ngIf="head.mappedProperty">
        <td>
          {{ head.dataType ==='dropDown' ? tableData[head.mappedName]: head.dataType ==='date' ?
          (tableData[head.mappedProperty] | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy') : tableData[head.mappedProperty] }}
        </td>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-template #noDataToShow> No Data to Show </ng-template>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Is the #viewable reference on containing ng-template has any condition not to display its content if no tableData??

Comment: @AliJamal for this line=> <ng-container *ngIf="tableData.isEditable; else viewable">

Comment: based on the above comment tableData is an object that has a boolean value isEditable, yet in your snippet you are checking against tableData.length which indicate that tableData is an array as length property exist on arrays?? I hope this will put you on the correct path to get this working

Comment: Sorry, there is a array object "data" from which i have got tableData. I changed it in my code, but still result same

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution using `*matNoDataRow`:

```
<tr class="mat-row" *matNoDataRow>
  <td class="mat-cell" colspan="9999">
    No record display.
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: can you check your chat box